# Vertx Rx-Java: reasons for eventBus subscriber being unsubscribed

Tags: java, rx-java, vert.x

I am using vertx with rx-java.

I have a verticle which subscribes to events on eventBus with specific addresses:

```
eventBus.localConsumer(some_addres)
        .toObservable()
        .subscribe(message -> {
                     ...
                     message.reply(...);
                   })
... same for other addresses...
```

And other verticles are sending events using:

```
eventBus.rxSend(some_address, message, new DeployOptions().setSendTimeout(60000));
```

Verticles are created via `RxHelper.deployVerticle`.

And everything worked fine, however after some time one of the addresses got unsubscribed, and all requests for this event now fail with `ReplyException: No handlers for address some_ddress` error, all other addresss are still subscribed.

I don't see any vertx errors in the logs.

What can be the reason for consumer being unsubscribed automatically from particaller address it was listening too?

As far as I understand: if the request fails with error or timeout it shouldn't lead to unsubscription, so I don't really understand what can lead to such behaviour then.(I don't have any explicit `unsubscribe` calls at all)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appeared that the prblem was that the code before `message.reply` sometimes threw an exception:

```
eventBus.localConsumer(some_addres)
    .toObservable()
    .subscribe(message -> {
                 ... <-- exception here
                 message.reply(...);
               })
```

Simple fix:

```
    eventBus.localConsumer(some_addres)
    .toObservable()
    .subscribe(message -> {
                 try {
                     ... <-- exception here
                     message.reply(...);
                 } catch (Exception e) {
                     ...handle exception...
                    message.error(...);
                 }
               })
```